# how to connect esp8266 softAp with android app

Tags: java, android, esp8266

I want some brief idea/links for reference to start how to connect esp8266 router/access point with an android app.In esp8266 static ip is 192.168.4.1  wants to control led blink or other feautre with an android app .
how to make establish connection between esp8266 and android app .

Comment: See this and understand every class https://github.com/EspressifApp/IOT-Espressif-Android It may be help you

Comment: How to look into that android flow from which folder i have to start tell me for better understandability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android side it's just network communication without any features. Take a look at [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/index.html) and tutorials like [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/simple-connection-example-part-ii-tcp-communication). Everything depends on esp8266 firmware:

- if it implements `HTTP web server` You can use [HttpUrlConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) and GET or POST requests on Android side and corresponding script on esp8266 side;
- if it implements `ServerSocket` You can use [Socket](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html) connection an implement [Socket Client](http://androidsrc.net/android-client-server-using-sockets-client-implementation/) on Android side.

**Update:**

Socket communication with `esp8266` You should do it in separate (not UI) thread. Full example is something like that:

```
class SocketClientThread implements Runnable {
        DataInputStream dis;
        DataOutputStream dos;
        String strResponseData;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("<address>");
                clientSocket = new Socket(serverAddr, <port_number - 80 in your example>);
                dos = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                dis = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());

                // now you can write data to stream
                dos.writeUTF("Hello");

                // you can also read data from stream
                strResponseData = dis.readUTF();


            } catch (UnknownHostException ignore) {
            } catch (IOException ignore) {
            }

            finally{
                if (clientSocket != null){
                    try {
                        clientSocket.close();
                    } 
                    catch (IOException ignore) {
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

And than You can use SocketClientThread this way:

```
Thread socketClientThread;
socketClientThread = new Thread(new SocketClientThread());
socketClientThread.start();
```

Comment: I agreed with your point . But want to ask one doubt socket connection socket server - esp8266 and socket client - android app right ?? #include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>                                                      
WiFiServer server(80);                                                              WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);
WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);

IPAddress apip = WiFi.softAPIP();                                            server.begin();                                                                            This is socket Connection or HTTP Webserver

Comment: "#include <WiFiClient.h> WiFiServer server(80);" - yes, seems it's code for `Socket` communication. Please see updated answer for example.

Comment: Thanks for info..!!